# Orbot Stops Forwarding in VPN Mode

Tags: orbot, vpn, android

Using Android, I have noticed that when my Wi-Fi is dropped for a few moments then reconnects Orbot still works but apps VPN mode does not. Is there a fix for this issue? To be clear, I am still connected to Tor but not able to use apps connected through VPN mode.

Comment: Do they stay that way permanently? Sometime mine seems to "freeze" like that and I need to go into orbot and swipe left or right on the onion to get a new identity and that seems to wake it back up for whatever sleep mode it had got itself into.

Comment: It stays that way until I manually shutdown Orbot, turn off VPN mode, turn Orbot back on, then finally turn VPN mode back on.